# In Access VBA, how do I copy fields which consist of Attachments from single record to another table?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I tried using SQL but with no success. I then tried DAO, the other fields 
seems to work but the column which holds attachments fails. Has someone done this before?

```
Private Sub copyfromtblA_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs3 As DAO.Recordset2
'Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("tblA")
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("tblB")

With rs2
rs2.AddNew
rs2.Fields("ItemNo").Value = Me.ItemNo.Value
rs2.Fields("Quantity").Value = Me.Quantity.Value
rs2.Fields("itemName").Value = Me.itemName.Value
'This is were I get the error since this field contains images as attachments
rs2.Fields("ItemImage").Value = Me.itemImage.Value


rs2.Update
rs1.MoveNext

End With
rs2.Close

Form.Requery
Set rs2 = Nothing
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Attachment is a table, you should create two recordsets with data type Recordset2, assign to them the `Value` property of the field with attachments and copy fields "FileData" and "FileName" (names fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub copyfromtblA_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsAtt1 As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rsAtt2 As DAO.Recordset2

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("tblB")
    With Me.Recordset
        rs2.AddNew
        rs2.Fields("ItemNo").Value = !ItemNo.Value
        rs2.Fields("Quantity").Value = !Quantity.Value
        rs2.Fields("itemName").Value = !itemName.Value
        Set rsAtt1 = !ItemImage.Value
        Set rsAtt2 = rs2!ItemImage.Value
        With rsAtt1
            Do While Not .EOF
                rsAtt2.AddNew
                rsAtt2.Fields("FileData") = .Fields("FileData")
                rsAtt2.Fields("FileName") = .Fields("FileName")
                rsAtt2.Update
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
        rs2.Update
    End With
    rs2.Close
    Set rs2 = Nothing
    rsAtt1.Close
    Set rsAtt1 = Nothing
    'I was getting an error here! removing the "rsAtt2.Close" solved the problem
    'rsAtt2.Close
    Set rsAtt2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: S, Many thanks. The code works well but at the moment, It copies all records from tblA. I am interested in only the current record which is displayed on the form. If I use "Me" keyword instead of the !, The records are repeated.

Comment: If your form based on tblA, then just remove outer cycle and clone form's recordset to rs1. I updated the code.

Comment: The only problem is, since the rows have different attachments, the latest code is capturing the attachment from the first record and passing it onto all other rows. I still have no clue on how to get around it.

Comment: S, is there a reason why the attachment file is the same for all the other records?

Comment: If you need to copy from the current row in the form, you can use directly form's recordset, see updated code.

Comment: S, I was getting an error on "rsAtt2.Close" removing it solved the problem. You have saved me. Many many thanks!