# Runtime error while trying to copy records

Tags: vba, ms-access

In the code below, I am trying to create copies of all records that are related to a single JobID. This is to create an identical job with a new ID for revision purposes. The code is:

```
Public Function CreateRevisions()

Dim lngOldID As Long    'change from long if text
Dim lngNewID As Long
Dim rsS As Recordset    'source recordset
Dim rsT As Recordset    'target recordset
Dim fld As Field

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord        'Save the record, to make sure all data is saved in table

lngOldID = Forms!JobQuote!JobID

'Copy the main table

Set rsS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblJobDetails where JobID=" & lngOldID, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsT = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblJobDetails", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

rsT.AddNew
For Each fld In rsS.Fields
    rsT.Fields(fld.Name) = fld
Next
lngNewID = rsT!JobID
rsT.Update

'Copies Drawings

Set rsS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblDrawings where JobID=" & lngOldID, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsT = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblDrawings", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

rsT.AddNew
rsT!JobID = lngNewID
For Each fld In rsS.Fields
    If fld.Name <> "JobID" Then
        rsT.Fields(fld.Name) = fld
    End If
Next
rsT.Update
```

The "Copies Drawings" part repeats several times, but does it for different tables. I get a run time error on `rsT.Fields(fld.Name) = fld`. It is run-time error `64224: Method of 'Value' of object 'Field2' failed`.

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: You can debug the code adding a breakpoint and using `F8`. Just to check, is there any field that is multivalue in the table? Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/49245029/1521579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you might be missing to specify the objects as DAO objects, and the record should be updated before you retrieve the new ID.

Second, it might be simpler and much faster to use the RecordsetClone already at hand.

This is actual code from a working form and subform:

```vb
Private Sub CopyButton_Click()

    Dim rst         As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstAdd      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld         As DAO.Field
    Dim Count       As Integer
    Dim Item        As Integer
    Dim Bookmark    As Variant
    Dim OldId       As Long
    Dim NewId       As Long
    
    ' Copy parent record.
    Set rstAdd = Me.RecordsetClone
    Set rst = rstAdd.Clone
    
    ' Move to current record.
    rst.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
    OldId = rst!Id.Value
    With rstAdd
        .AddNew
        For Each fld In .Fields
            With fld
                If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                    ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                Else
                    .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                End If
            End With
        Next
        .Update
        ' Pick Id of the new record.
        .MoveLast
        NewId = !Id.Value
    End With
    ' Store location of new record.
    Bookmark = rstAdd.Bookmark
    
    ' Copy child records 1.
    ' If a subform is present:
'    Set rstAdd = Me!subChild1.Form.RecordsetClone
    ' If a subform is not present, retrieve records from the child table:
    Set rstAdd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblChild1 Where FK = " & OldId & "")
    Set rst = rstAdd.Clone

    If rstAdd.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rstAdd.MoveLast
        rstAdd.MoveFirst
    End If
    Count = rstAdd.RecordCount
    For Item = 1 To Count
        With rstAdd
            .AddNew
            For Each fld In .Fields
                With fld
                    If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                        ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                    ElseIf .Name = "FK" Then
                        ' Skip master/child field.
                        .Value = NewId
                    Else
                        .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            .Update
        End With
        rst.MoveNext
    Next

    ' Copy child records 2.
    ' If a subform is present:
    Set rstAdd = Me!subChild2.Form.RecordsetClone
    ' If a subform is not present, retrieve records from the child table:
    ' Set rstAdd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblChild2 Where FK = " & OldId & "")
    Set rst = rstAdd.Clone

    If rstAdd.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rstAdd.MoveLast
        rstAdd.MoveFirst
    End If
    Count = rstAdd.RecordCount
    For Item = 1 To Count
        With rstAdd
            .AddNew
            For Each fld In .Fields
                With fld
                    If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                        ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                    ElseIf .Name = "FK" Then
                        ' Skip master/child field.
                        .Value = NewId
                    Else
                        .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            .Update
        End With
        rst.MoveNext
    Next

    rst.Close
    rstAdd.Close
    
    ' Move to the new recordcopy.
    Me.Bookmark = Bookmark
    
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rstAdd = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I am unfortunately getting an error ```Invalid arugment``` on ```.Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value```. So roughly same line, but now a different error.

Comment: Have you checked for multivalued fields? @Tmyers

Comment: @Andre has a point. At least, double-check your code, as the answer as posted is verified code.

Comment: I don't know the term as I am relatively new to this. Reading up on it real quick.

Comment: Based on the article I just read, no. I don't have multi-value fields. There are text fields, but every field is storing "one" value.

Comment: I think the problem may possibly like in the fact I have an attachment field. Could that be what is causing it?

Edit: Verified that it was in fact the attachment field as the code worked when I removed it. I will have to rethink how to handle that.

Comment: Indeed. Should the attachments not be copied, ignore this field - like other field types are excluded.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, what would I have to modify to get it to exclude and/or include an attachment field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780476/in-access-vba-how-do-i-copy-fields-which-consist-of-attachments-from-single-rec

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it won't compile or run unless recordset and field object variables are declared as DAO type.

Consider alternative which doesn't care about recordset type and doesn't require field variable:

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 0 To rsS.Fields.Count - 1
    rsT(rsS(i).Name) = rsS(i)
Next
```

Comment: When used in a loop of a collection, fld will be "set" to one item of the collection for each loop and, if you debug the loop, IntelliSense will display normally.

Comment: That's what I would have expected but when I tried OP's code it won't compile or run. It errors on `fld.Name`. I tried declaring recordset as DAO but didn't think to also declare field as DAO. That does make a difference. Revised my answer and code is a valid option.