# Is there any way for inserting an attachment file from one table to another in ms-access VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

hello everyone I'm new to the MS Access VBA code.

Actually, I want to make two tables for my customers in our company the first one is the inquiry table, using a form in MS Access I insert all the needed information for an inquiry.
After that, the customer approved the price of the inquiry, I checked a check box called "ordered" in my form, and all the information will insert into another table called Orders.

I want to insert an attachment field in my inquiry table and after the customer approves the price, by checking the check box in the inquiry form all the information including the attachment field will be transferred into the orders table fields.

but using "insert into" command will make an error "an insert into query cannot contain a multi-value field"

I should do this because we have lots of inquiries but fewer orders,
and finding orders among the lots of inquiries is difficult.

here is my code:

```
Private Sub Ordered_Click()
Dim Inquirycodevar As Integer

Inquirycodevar = Me.Inquirycode.Value

If IsNull(Me.Inquirycode) Or IsNull(Me.Customer.Value) Or IsNull(Me.Cavitynumber.Value) Or IsNull(Me.Productionmethod.Value) Or IsNull(Me.Partname.Value) Then

MsgBox "fill all the fields"

Me.Ordered.Value = 0

Else



DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into Orderss (Inquirycode, Customer, partname, Cavitynumber, Productionmethod, Price, Comment, Picture, Ordered, Datye)" & _
"select QU.Inquirycode, QU.Customer, QU.partname, QU.Cavitynumber, QU.Productionmethod, QU.Price, QU.Comment, QU.Picture, QU.Ordered, Date() as expr1 " & _
"from QU where QU.Inquirycode= " & Inquirycodevar



DoCmd.RunSQL "delete * from QU where QU.Inquirycode=" & Inquirycodevar


End If

End Sub
```

the picture field is the attachment field
I appreciate if anybody can help me
Thank you so much

Comment: Embedding files in attachment field uses up Access 2GB size limit. And you want multiple copies of embedded file saved? This is really bad design.

Comment: Duplicating data is bad design. Instead of two tables could just have a Status field with values like Inquiry, Pending, Final, Cancel. Or have several date fields: InquiryDate, OrderDate. Or if the original inquiry date is not important, have StatusType field and StatusDate field. Finding inquiries that progressed to order status would be simple.

Comment: thank you for comments
as i wrote on my question the number of inquiries is more than number of orders
and making just check box makes it difficult for our co-worker to find an order among hundreds of inquiry,

Comment: @June7 is right. And it is not the users that will search hundreds of inquiries; you filter on that and have Access do it for you.

Comment: Users should not be working directly with tables and queries. Build a search form - review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. And I did not suggest a checkbox but that is an option.

Comment: thank you all guys, I just changed my code, like the code is written in the following question.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780476/in-access-vba-how-do-i-copy-fields-which-consist-of-attachments-from-single-rec)